# Adobe Photoshop (2020) - Is there any chance to programmatically change position of "Options/Control Bar" OR edit a "Custom Workspace"?

Tags: photoshop, photoshop-script

So…
My (very) old **16:10** *(1920 x **1200**px)* monitor died a couple of days ago and I had to replace it in a hurry with a **16:9** one *(1920 x **1080**px)*.
As I already suspected those missing 120px have caused some troubles in most of my "custom workspaces", as I usually prefer having "options/control bars" at the bottom of the screen.
I managed to easily solve the issue in Illustrator, but **not** in Photoshop.
So, I've tried to edit my Custom Workspace in TextMate, but there doesn't seem to be a way to tell the corresponding ID for the "options/control bar".

Since I saved ALL tools behaviors, shortcuts and other stuff *within* my Custom Workspace, it doesn't seem an option to rebuild one from scratch *(unless I'm not **sure** there are no other solution, obviously)*.

I've also tried to dig for an Applescript (I'm on MacOsX 10.13.6) to *«tell System Events to tell Photoshop to tell option/control bar»…* "Hey! Move yourself UP by 120px!".
But, still, I have NO idea how to identify "options/control bar" in a programmatic way.

**Wrapping it all up**…
"I need to move up the Options/control bar, but I can't see it!"

And that's it… Hints?!
**TIA**! :)

_

Comment: I take it reset workspace didn't work. To my knowledge you can't script the position of windows & dialog boxes (custom UI - yes) but not the windows such as options or properties or brushes. You could have also deleted the preferences file (made a backup of if first!!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, guys.
Solved in the less "programmatically" way I can think of.

I just sent the workspace file (".pwd") to a friend who has a 16:10 monitor, asking her to load it in PS, choose it as a workspace, put the "Option/Control Bar" at the top and save it all.

Then I loaded it back to my PS and… done!

Thanks anyway ;)
_